# Place two banner images side by side on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two banner images (1024 x 609) side by side.
Website width is 1803px.
However It keeps showing one image in a row like:

image1

image2

I wanted to make it like:

image1image2

This is what I tried (Copied from w3schools.com)

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1352/5175/files/sample.jpg?v=1611329566" alt="Sample" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1352/5175/files/sample.jpg?v=1611329566" alt="Sample" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

after change .row section in CSS
to

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

it works like I intended

Answer (score 0):

Here is another responsive solution!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  margin: 2%;
  width: 45%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1352/5175/files/sample.jpg?v=1611329566" alt="Sample" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1352/5175/files/sample.jpg?v=1611329566" alt="Sample" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```